# python ff-mpeg not working on VM

Tags: python-2.7, ffmpeg

I have two Windows 2008 R2 64 bit servers with two different host providers (GoDaddy and company B). My python script runs successfully on GoDaddy's server. It doesn't run successfully on the server with company B.

I installed the same software on both servers:

- Python 2.7 for Windows 32 bit
- NumPY module
- SetupTools
- EchoNest API for Windows

The company B server is giving me an error related to an executable called en-ffmpeg.exe that uses the python ff-mpeg module. The exact error message is

> [dv @ 0x1449690]Can't determine profile of DV input stream.
>   C:\Music\song1.mp3: Error while opening file

The song.mp3 file exists. I installed the latest Windows updates on the server with Company B but still I get the error. I believe the error is because something is not configured properly on this server (missing libraries or drivers?). However, I don't know what that is!

Please help :)

UPDATED TO INCLUDE COMMAND AND ERROR OUTPUT FROM FFMPEG

COMMAND:

> c:\Python27>en-ffmpeg -i "C:\Music\song1.mp3" -y -ac 2 -ar 44100
>   "c:\users\x07 dmini~1\x07ppdata\local\temp\x02\tmpax82jf.wav"

FULL ERROR:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r17988-Komeil, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al
.
  configuration: --enable-memalign-hack --extra-cflags=-fno-common --enable-stat
ic --disable-shared --disable-debug --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-avfil
ter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-avisynth --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads
 --enable-libamr-nb --enable-libamr-wb --enable-libgsm --enable-libfaac --enable
-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable
-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid
  libavutil     50. 0. 0 / 50. 0. 0
  libavcodec    52.21. 0 / 52.21. 0
  libavformat   52.31. 1 / 52.31. 1
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Mar 15 2009 18:16:31, gcc: 4.3.0 20080305 (alpha-testing) mingw-20080
502
[dv @ 0x1449690]Can't determine profile of DV input stream.
C:\\Music\\song1.mp3: Error while opening file
```

I also tried removing the double back slashes from the command but got the same error.

Comment: If this involves ffmpeg you need to include the ffmpeg command and the complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: Updated to include ffmpeg error and output

Comment: It worked LordNeckbeard!! I am very grateful :) I just don't know why the old version works on my GoDaddy server but not with my other host provider. Weird. I don't think I can mark a comment as the answer. Do you want to write an official answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SVN-r17988` is absolutely ancient and is unsupported. User a newer ffmpeg from [Zeranoe FFmpeg Windows builds](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and it will work.

FFmpeg development is very active, and using the most recent build available (or compiling it yourself) will ensure that you're not experiencing a bug that has already been fixed.